# How to properly design solr4 schema for multivalued hierarchichal pivot facets

Tags: java, user-interface, faceted-search, solr4

I am to create an application which will allow searching for planets with certain kind of robots "living" on them. Of course the XML I am receiving with the data is send to me from [Vogsphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vogsphere#Vogsphere) and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<planet>
    <name>Iota Draconis b</name>
    <constellation>Draco</constellation>
    <meanRadius unit="km">44500</meanRadius>
    <robots>
        <robot category="autobot">
            <name>Optimus Prime</name>
            <properties>
                <property category="weapons">
                    <name>minigun</name>
                    <name>laser</name>
                </property>
                <property category="color">
                    <name>white</name>
                    <name>red</name>
                </property>
                <property category="energy">
                    <name>solar</name>
                    <name>battery</name>
                </property>
            </properties>
        </robot>
        <robot category="decepticon">
            <name>Megatron</name>
            <properties>
                <property category="weapons">
                    <name>minigun</name>
                    <name explanation="heat seaking missiles">rockets</name>
                </property>
                <property category="color">
                    <name>black</name>
                </property>
                <property category="movement">
                    <name>legs</name>
                    <name>wheels</name>
                </property>
            </properties>
        </robot>
    </robots>
</planet>
```

The example above is just for one planet, there are over 200.000 of them. So, the organizer of this nasty combat tournament wants to browse with facets created from the above XML data.

I have read some of the Earth documents about hierarchical pivot faceting, but I have found none which deals with multivalued fields also.

You see, each robot has a category (one of 10), name (one of 200) and a number of properties.

Each property has a category (one of 300, but a subset based on robot's name) and name(s) (several, but at least one out of hundreds, but a subset based on property's category).

Here is a picture of what could user interface look like:
[image: Browsing plants in search for robots]

In defend of Earth's intelligence, can someone help me out creating solr4 schema please?